# Что не так в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Выполняю регулярное выражение `(?<=[,.])0+$` на строке 3.0400000000000
Нули в конце не выделяются, что в нем не так и как поправить чтобы выделились необязательные нули?

Comment: а чем вот так `0+$` не подходит

Comment: Как выделать нули?

Comment: Может передвинуть скобку, чтобы 0+ оказалось внутри скобки?

Answer (score 0):

У вас `(?<=[,.])0+$` дословно означает: найди все нули *сразу* от точки или запятой и до конца строки. В `3.0400000000000` перед конечными нулями есть `4`.

Замените

```
([.,][0-9]*?)0+$
```

на `$1` или `\1` в зависимости от используемой библиотеки регулярных выражений или языка программирования.

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/768WOP/1).